# Find $ax^2+3x+b$ that goes through the given points using the least squares

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-equations, least-squares

The points are $ (2,1.5),(−1,1.7),(1,1.9)$.
I did:

$A = \left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 4 \\
    1 & -1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1  & 1
   \end{matrix} \right ] \\
x = \left [ \begin{matrix}
    b   \\
    3   \\
    a   
   \end{matrix} \right ]\\
b = \left [ \begin{matrix}
    1.5 \\
    1.7 \\
    1.9
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

I solved for $$A^TAx = A^Tb$$

I got the Cholesky decomposition of $A^TA$

[image]

Then I solved $Ly = A^Tb$ and got $$
\left [ \begin{matrix}
    51/10 \\
    16/5 \\
    48/5
   \end{matrix} \right ]$$$

The next part is where I am having a problem. Now I have to solve $L^tx = y$. I already have some values for x, so I multiplied $L^tx$ and made it equal to y and got a system of equations

[image]

[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: @Moo It's from my prof's exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3$ is not an unknown variable, so your solution is incorrect.
We have
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rrrrr}
2^2\cdot a &+3\cdot 2&+b&= &1.5 \\
 (-1)^2\cdot a&+3\cdot(-1)&+b&= &1.7 \\
 1^2\cdot a&+3\cdot 1&+b&= &1.9 \\
\end{array}\right.
$$
or
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rrrrr}
4a&+&b&= &-4.5 \\
a&+&b&= &4.7 \\
a&+&b&= &-1.1 \\
\end{array}\right.
$$
or
$$
Ay=d,
$$
where
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
4 & 1\\
1 & 1\\
1 & 1\\
\end{array}\right),\quad
d=\left(\begin{array}{r}
-4.5 \\
4.7 \\
1.9 \\
\end{array}\right),\quad
y=\left(\begin{array}{r}
a \\
b \\
\end{array}\right).
$$
This system has no solutions, thus, there is no curve of the form $ax^2+3x+b$ which goes exactly through the given points. It is only possible to find a least squares solution. This solution won't make a lot of practical sense since $a+b$ can't be equal to $4.7$ and $-1.1$ at the same time even approximately.
$$
y_{ls}=A^{+}d=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Td=\left(\begin{array}{r}
-2.1 \\
3.9 \\
\end{array}\right).
$$
Hence, the answer is $-2.1x^2+3x+3.9$.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I have one more question. When solving the equation can I always use Cholesky's decomposition? When do I use Cholesky and when do I use QR?

Comment: Also how do I verify the solution? (for when I am doing exercises on my own)

Comment: @Segmentation fault In terms of least squares, it doesn't matter which method you use to solve the system $A^TAx=A^Tb$. The result will be the same for any method.

Comment: @Segmentation fault You can use some math software to draw the curve and the points it must go through. For the problem under consideration, however, the result will not be impressive for the reason I indicated in the answer.